# Failed to attach Sqlite database with special charactesrs in the path

Tags: c#, sqlite, utf-8, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I use SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) and SQLite.Net-PCL extension. 
I work with databases in user local folder. Path to this folder contains username. So, sometimes it may contain special characters (e.g. 'š').
It works correctly when I create connection and open a database. However, the problem occurred when trying to attach another database. I always got exception "CannotOpen".

I suppose the problem is based on different encoding (UTF-8 in SQLite, UTF-16 in .Net) but I haven't managed to resolve it. 
Sqlite contains methods for opening database in UTF 16 (sqlite3_open16). But there is no such a method for SQL statements.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqlite1.db");
string dbPath2 = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqlite2.db");

using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath))
{                
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand("ATTACH '" + dbPath2 + "' AS second;");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   // -> it throws "CannotOpen" exception if dbPath2 contains special characters
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it supports attached database in windows 8.1.I will have a test and post the result here later.

Comment: Thanks Mattew. I hope it is supported. I managed to attach database but only if a path haven't contained special unicode characters. I have tried it also with Sqlite for UWP with Windows 10. The result was the same.